# How to add multiline comment in HeaderDoc

Tags: ios, objective-c, documentation, headerdoc

This is my code

```
/**
 *    In touchesBegan: it is considered if it was succesfull click. Automatically changes on/off images
 */
@interface WOC_OnOffImageButton : SKSpriteNode
```

And when I do alt-click on `WOC_OnOffImageButton` in popup inside `Description` I get `In touchesBegan: it is considered if it was succesfull click. Automatically changes on/off images` all in one line.

I would like to have new line between `... click. Automatically...`, because that it is easier to read.

**Question**
Is it posible, and if so, how to do it ?

Comment: Yes I did, and I tried \n, <br> and there variations, but it did not worked. :-(

Comment: Did you try inserting an actual newline between the two lines? And which popup are you talking about? The Xcode autocomplete popup cannot display multiline comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Yes, AppleDoc supports multiline comments. Here's how you use them:

```
 /**
 *    In touchesBegan: it is considered if it was succesfull click.
 *
 *    Automatically changes on/off images
 */
```

The key is to put asterisks on the new lines. You may need to Save (`Cmd+S`) and/or Clean (`Cmd+Shift+K`) your project to see the result in a popup window.

Comment: `Cmd+Shift+K` is **MUST**, otherwise it is not working. Is there way to reduce whitespace between lines on popup descriptor ? I just want one line after the other. With no so much white space in between.

Comment: It's an old answer but to clarify (tested in xCode 9.3), One blank line is must between two lines of text to make text appear in new line (* - asterisks is not must)